# Chart.js Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"line" | "bar" | "scatter"

Tags: javascript, chart.js, angular11

```
client:159 src/app/analytics-page/analytics-page.component.ts:211:26 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ type: string; options: { responsive: boolean; }; data: { labels: string[]; datasets: { label: string; data: number[]; borderColor: string; steppedLine: boolean; fill: boolean; }[]; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChartConfiguration<"line" | "bar" | "scatter" | "bubble" | "pie" | "doughnut" | "polarArea" | "radar", number[], string>'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"line" | "bar" | "scatter" | "bubble" | "pie" | "doughnut" | "polarArea" | "radar"'.

211       new Chart(gainCtx, createChartConfig(gainConfig))
```

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnDestroy, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
import {AnalyticsService} from '../shared/services/analytics.service'
import {AnalyticsPage, ChartConfig} from '../shared/interfaces'
import {Chart} from 'chart.js'
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-analytics-page',
  templateUrl: './analytics-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./analytics-page.component.scss']
})
export class AnalyticsPageComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {

  @ViewChild('gain') gainRef!: ElementRef
  @ViewChild('order') orderRef!: ElementRef

  aSub!: Subscription
  average!: number
  pending = true

  constructor(private service: AnalyticsService) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const gainConfig: any = {
      label: 'Выручка',
      color: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
    }

    const orderConfig: any = {
      label: 'Заказы',
      color: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'
    }

    this.aSub = this.service.getAnalytics().subscribe((data: AnalyticsPage) => {
      this.average = data.average

      gainConfig.labels = data.chart.map(item => item.label)
      gainConfig.data = data.chart.map(item => item.gain)

      orderConfig.labels = data.chart.map(item => item.label)
      orderConfig.data = data.chart.map(item => item.order)

      // **** Gain ****
      // gainConfig.labels.push('08.05.2018')
      // gainConfig.labels.push('09.05.2018')
      // gainConfig.data.push(1500)
      // gainConfig.data.push(700)
      // **** /Gain ****

      // **** Order ****
      // orderConfig.labels.push('08.05.2018')
      // orderConfig.labels.push('09.05.2018')
      // orderConfig.data.push(8)
      // orderConfig.data.push(2)
      // **** /Order ****

      const gainCtx = this.gainRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d')
      const orderCtx = this.orderRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d')
      gainCtx.canvas.height = '300px'
      orderCtx.canvas.height = '300px'

      new Chart(gainCtx, createChartConfig(gainConfig))
      new Chart(orderCtx, createChartConfig(orderConfig))

      this.pending = false
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.aSub) {
      this.aSub.unsubscribe()
    }
  }

}


function createChartConfig({labels, data, label, color}: ChartConfig) {
  return {
    type: 'line',
    options: {
      responsive: true
    },
    data: {
      labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label, data,
          borderColor: color,
          steppedLine: false,
          fill: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is in `type: 'line',`. Chart.js is not working, it not work with any type, throws error.

Comment: Try specifying the return type, `function createChartConfig({labels, data, label, color}: ChartConfig): ChartConfiguration<"line"> {`

Comment: I did as you say and it throws new error: core.js:6162 ERROR Error: "line" is not a registered controller.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like your TypeScript compiler is complaining because the chart `type` property is a specific type rather than a string.

**Option 1:**

Import ChartType and cast `type` as `ChartType`.

```
import {  Chart, ChartType, ...} from 'chart.js';

 ...

function createChartConfig({labels, data, label, color}: ChartConfig) {
  return {
    type: 'line' as ChartType,
    options: {
   ...
```

**Option 2:** (The easier/hacky way)

Cast the entire config as any.

```
new Chart(gainCtx, createChartConfig(gainConfig) as any);
```

In any case, you will need to import and register the needed controllers, elements, scales, etc. Registering `registerables` registers everything, but it is better to register only what you require for your specific chart.  See the [Integration instructions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html) for more information.

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
...
Chart.register(...registerables);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error, when Googling the error this SO question came up so I will drop a related solution here.

This is somewhat of a work around, but I was getting this error:

```
Types of property 'borderJoinStyle' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"miter" | "round" | "bevel" | ((ctx: ScriptableContext<"line">, options: AnyObject) => CanvasLineJoin | undefined) | undefined'.
```

To resolve the issue I changed my setting from `borderJoinStyle: "miter"` to `borderJoinStyle: "miter" as const`.

I was also getting this error:

```
Types of property 'borderCapStyle' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"butt" | "round" | "square" | ((ctx: ScriptableContext<"line">, options: AnyObject) => CanvasLineCap | undefined) | undefined'.
```

I made a similar change as above. Changed from `borderCapStyle: "round"` to `borderCapStyle: "round" as const`

I found the answer on Github:

https://github.com/apexcharts/react-apexcharts/issues/347#issuecomment-932848265

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to include the library from **chart.js/auto**, and not from <s>chart.js</s>.

I wrote about this in more detail in a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67060070/chart-js-core-js6162-error-error-line-is-not-a-registered-controller/74909246#74909246).

To avoid an error, the function for generating configurations *createChartConfig()* must return data corresponding to the interface signature **ChartConfiguration**,
or a generalization **<ChartConfiguration>** must be written for the called function.
Accordingly, it is also necessary to connect **ChartConfiguration** from **chart.js/auto**.

The final working code will look like this:

```
import { Chart, ChartConfiguration } from 'chart.js/auto'

ngAfterViewInit (): void {
   // .......
   new Chart(gainCtx, <ChartConfiguration>createChartConfig(gainConf)) // with generic
   new Chart(orderCtx, createChartConfig(orderConfig)) // without generic
   // .......
}

function createChartConfig ({ labels, data, label, color}: { labels: string[], data: number[], label: string, color: string }): ChartConfiguration {
  return {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels,
      datasets: [{
        label,
        data,
        borderColor: color,
        // steppedLine: false, // v. 3.x <-- deprecated and was removed
        stepped: false, // v. 4
        fill: false
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true
    }
  }
}
```