# Chart.js core.js:6162 ERROR Error: "line" is not a registered controller

Tags: angular, chart.js

```js
 const gainContext = this.gainRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d')
  gainContext.canvas.height = '300px'

  new Chart(gainContext, createChartConfig(gainConfig))


function createChartConfig({type, labels, data, label, color}: ChartConfig): ChartConfiguration<"line">{

  console.log('3 Chart.defaults', Chart.defaults)

  return {
type: "line",
data: {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label,
      data,
      borderColor: color,
      stepped: false,
      fill: false
    }
  ]
}
  }
```

This is not working: It not recognize the type property as it must in official documentation.

let myChart = new Chart(gainContext, {
type: 'line',

What I do wrong?

Comment: I found the problem and decision: 

 1. You have to import all needed stuff from Chart.js
 import { Chart, ChartConfiguration, LineController, LineElement, PointElement, LinearScale, Title, CategoryScale } from 'chart.js'

 2. And then register it in component before instantiating new Chart 

 Chart.register(LineController, LineElement, PointElement, LinearScale, Title, CategoryScale);

And error is gone, chart is working!

Comment: This worked for me aswell, i am using vue/nuxt and had problems getting vue-chart.js to work. Ended up using chart.js and this comment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 130):

We can do this in three ways

### Using 'auto'

Import everything, in one line:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```

### Old way

```js
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
```

and then register all the components

```js
Chart.register(...registerables);
```

### Individual import

By importing and registering the required part as commented by @Tatyana Molchanova

```js
import { Chart, ChartConfiguration, LineController, LineElement, PointElement, LinearScale, Title} from 'chart.js'
```

and then register it in component before instantiating new Chart

```js
Chart.register(LineController, LineElement, PointElement, LinearScale, Title);
```

Comment: Just tested! import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'; works like magic!

Comment: This is all documented here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc

Comment: thanks, just import Chart from 'chart.js/auto' worked for me (parcel). What an annoying library behavior :(

Comment: import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';   Works for me. Thank you.

Comment: @crimson_king I don't know about "all"; I swear they forgot to mention calling `Chart.register()` anywhere

Comment: 2nd approach for me, thanks!

Comment: Adding to @crimson_king comment, the `Chart.register()` and `Error: "thing" is not a registered controller` is documented in [the next page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html#tree-shaking).

Answer (score 29):

Angular 12 here.  Gaurev's answer worked for me.  I had to use:

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
export class ChartTest {

  constructor() {
    Chart.register(...registerables);
  }

  // methods to actually make the chart per documentation
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You get an error because you need to include Chart from chart.js/auto, and not from chart.js:

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js/auto'
```

This is clearly stated in the documentation:

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#helper-functions

Or you need to use dynamic import like this:

```
const { Chart } = await import('chart.js')
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#commonjs

*checked on version ^4 Сhart.js

Answer (score 4):

please upgrade npm package, its worked for me

```
npm i chart.js@2.9.4
```

Comment: Readers beware: 2.9.4 is no longer the latest major version.

Comment: Thanks man, this is a good solution when you use latest version of react or next, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in Angular 14 as Bob Ramsey replied:

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';

export class ChartTest {

   constructor() {
      Chart.register(...registerables);
  }

  // methods to actually make the chart per documentation
}
```