# I am getting this error when I deployed my React app on Github "Error: "line" is not a registered controller."

Tags: reactjs, charts

I created a React app and it works fine on my local machine, but after deployment in the Github I am getting the following error:

```
"Error: "line" is not a registered controller."
```

I read multiple solutions from stackoverflow, but none of them solved the issue. Here you can see the links for the articles which didn't work .

[Chart.js core.js:6162 ERROR Error: "line" is not a registered controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67060070/chart-js-core-js6162-error-error-line-is-not-a-registered-controller)

https://www.coder.work/article/7595319

Did someone had similar issue? How can I fix this bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way how to solve this issue. All I had to to do was import it from  chart.js then import chart from "react-chartjs-2"

```
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  LinearScale,
  CategoryScale,
  BarElement,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Legend,
  Tooltip,
  registerables as registerablesJS
} from "chart.js";
import { Chart} from "react-chartjs-2";
ChartJS.register(...registerablesJS);



ChartJS.register(
  LinearScale,
  CategoryScale,
  BarElement,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Legend,
  Tooltip
);
```

Comment: Using registerables registers everything, even the elements you are not using. I am having the same issue but couldn't find a proper answer yet...